# ValueError: could not convert string to float: Error in Sklearn and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to work on a classification model. I'm using SGDClassifier()

My df has two columns [full_text, label]

and
below is my script

```
df_scraped = pd.read_csv('data/labeled_tweets.csv') df_public = pd.read_csv('data/public_data_labeled.csv')

df_scraped.drop_duplicates(inplace = True) df_scraped.drop('id', axis
= 'columns', inplace = True) df_public.drop_duplicates(inplace = True) df = pd.concat([df_scraped, df_public])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    text = row['full_text']
    text = ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", text).split())
    df.at[index,'full_text'] = text

df['label'] = df.label.map({'Offensive': 1, 'Non-offensive': 0})

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['full_text'],
                                                    df['label'],
                                                    random_state=99)

print (X_train['full_text'].head(3))

print('Number of rows in the total set: {}'.format(df.shape[0])) print('Number of rows in the training set: {}'.format(X_train.shape[0])) print('Number of rows in the test set: {}'.format(X_test.shape[0]))

count_vector = CountVectorizer(stop_words = 'english', lowercase = True) training_data = count_vector.fit_transform(X_train) testing_data
= count_vector.transform(X_test)

# Dict for parameters param_grid = {
    'alpha' : [0.095, 0.0002, 0.0003],
    'max_iter' : [2500, 3000, 4000] }

print(X_train[0])

### label encode the categorical values and convert them to numbers le = LabelEncoder() le.fit(X_train[1].astype(str)) X_train[1] = le.transform(X_train[1].astype(str)) X_test[1] = le.transform(X_test[1].astype(str))

### train the model clf_sgd = SGDClassifier() clf_sgd.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

On running this script I get error
KeyError: 'full_text'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

I'm failing to understand why it is happening. I am using encoder to encode string to float so that I can use it in model.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I tried to follow this https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/discussion/54683 for the encoding part.

Comment: What line exactly causes the error ? Have you verified that your df does indeed contain column full_text ? The error message suggests otherwise.